# has_many and belongs_to giving errors in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new with ruby and rails and have been struggling with this issue for a few days. I know I had another association like this elsewhere in my app, but this one just isn't working.

I have a has_many and belongs_to relationship between my Game model and Character model.

*game.rb*

```
has_many :characters
```

*character.rb*

```
belongs_to :game, :foreign_key => 'game_id'
```

I want to be able to store the game_id in the character and then show the game's name in the view like this:

```
<%= @character.game.name %>
```

But I get this error:

> NoMethodError in Characters#show
>
> Showing .../rpglegion/app/views/characters/show.html.erb where line #5 raised:
>
> undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
>
> Extracted source (around line #5):
>
> 5:     <%= @character.game.name %>
>
> Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
>
> app/views/characters/show.html.erb:5:in >_app_views_characters_show_html_erb___872566584_80495980'
>   app/controllers/characters_controller.rb:20:in `show'

_characters_controller.rb_

```
def show
  @character = Character.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format| #line 20
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @character }
  end
end
```

I can't figure out what exactly I'm doing wrong that the associations aren't working. Can somebody please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, "game_id" is implied by the belongs_to association, so you can remove the :foreign_key part.

Second, does the @character actually have a game_id set to a game? If not, open a console, find the character you're looking at, and set it's game_id to an existing game. For instance:

```
character = Character.find_by_id(some_character_id)
character.game = Game.find_by_id(some_game_id)
character.save
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to verify what you are doing is right or wrong is through rails console. So type rails c on command line. type Character.all or Character.find(character_id)
See if your game_id has value in it. if not there is you problem....

Comment: Thank you both. I feel so stupid now that I know what the issue was. Once I got into the rails console, I found that the game_id assigned to the character was old and didn't exist in the table any more. Next time, I will go right to the console first!